# Compute percentage for bigdecimals

Tags: java

I haven't found any native method to do this, so I created my own in a helper class:

```
public static BigDecimal percentage(BigDecimal base, BigDecimal pct){
    return base.multiply(pct).divide(new BigDecimal(100));
}
```

But I don't quite like it, I wonder if the API has something similar. The Number class (ancestor of BigDecimal) would be a nice place.

Comment: Why don't you like it?  What's wrong with it?

Comment: I think about how many other programmers are going to create the same method, it's just DRY. Even the simplest calculator has a percentage button. I can't understand why the class doesn't have it.

Comment: @LluisMartinez: The problem here is precision. When you divide two ``BigDecimal``s (which you do when calculating percentage), you'd have to provide a proper rounding mode. I suppose that's why the class does not provide a ``percentage()`` method. Just look at ``BigDecimal``, there are six ``divide()`` methods already with different signatures. Providing a percentage method, you'd have to add another 6+ methods and ultimately that would bloat up the entire implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feel free to subclass `BigDecimal` and add that method. Beyond that, what do you expect? You know where to find the API and confirm that the class you would like to have that method doesn't. Personally, I'd say the functionality is so trivial that there wouldn't be much of a point in having it in the standard API.

Comment: Yes it's trivial but used very often, at least in certain type of applications.

Comment: I agree. Although trivial, but is used a lot

Answer (score 34):

I don't think there is an API for that (I never needed it).
Your solution seams good to me, maybe you just add the constant `ONE_HUNDRED`:

```
public static final BigDecimal ONE_HUNDRED = new BigDecimal(100);

public static BigDecimal percentage(BigDecimal base, BigDecimal pct){
    return base.multiply(pct).divide(ONE_HUNDRED);
}
```

*probably not that much gain, only if called* very *often*

eventually put it in some Util class...

Comment: BigDecimal has ZERO, ONE and TEN. But not HUNDRED or THOUSAND. Curioso!

Comment: @Lluis : `ZERO` and `ONE` are pretty old (Java 1.2); `TEN` is also getting old, since Java 5; maybe we get HUNDERT with Java 7 :-) but not a big deal to create it anyway... Saludos!

Answer (score 15):

You may want to implement the division by 100 using `BigDecimal.scaleByPowerOfTen(-2)`.

It adds up if you do it a million times. It is much faster in my experience.

There is also a similar method `BigDecimal.movePointLeft(2)` - see [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25454734/4791255) for details and decide which one works better for you.

Answer (score 5):

See also [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). You can use the parent's factory method `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/698506/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/698354/230513), [*et al.*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjava%5D%20BigDecimal%20NumberFormat.getPercentInstance)

Comment: In the questions you linked it's just printing a decimal as a percentage (like .25 shown as "25%"): are you sure you can *compute* a percentage using DecimalFormat? Can you add an example of how to compute 37% of 12523 using this technique?

Comment: This is a reasonable concern: I would advocate performing the computation with the maximum precision available—e.g. `double` in Java—and letting the format instance perform the prescribed [rounding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html); a similar issue is examined [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284149/6692).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `UNNECESSARY` rounding mode and scale of `2`, if your number is an *integer*.

It would be like this:

```
// rate == 0.10
BigDecimal rate = BigDecimal.TEN
        .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100), 2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
```

This way you can also avoid facing warnings like:

`BigDecimal.divide()' called without a rounding mode argument`

without needing to suppress them.