# how to convert percentage String to BigDecimal?

Tags: java

In java, how to convert percentage String to BigDecimal ?

Thanks

```
String percentage = "10%";
BigDecimal d ; // I want to get 0.1
```

Comment: seems like duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109860/compute-percentage-for-bigdecimals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(percentage.trim().replace("%", "")).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
```

Answer (score 15):

Try `new DecimalFormat("0.0#%").parse(percentage)`

Comment: Here Namal provide the answer in one line method, instead of again dividing. Good.

Comment: Just remember that this won't work with something like "10.5%".

Comment: @RasmusFaber it will

Comment: The internal cacluation of DecimalFormat suffers from precision loss! new DecimalFormat("0.0#%").parse("0.9%") -> 0.009000000000000001

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know that the `%` symbol will always be at the end of your `String`:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(percentage.substring(0, percentage.length()-1));
d.divide(100); // '%' means 'per hundred', so divide by 100
```

If you don't know that the `%` symbol will be there:

```
percentage = percentage.replaceAll("%", ""); // Check for the '%' symbol and delete it.

BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(percentage.substring(0, percentage.length()-1));
d.divide(new BigDecimal(100));
```

Comment: There is no `divide(int)` within `BigDecimal` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0%");
    f.setParseBigDecimal(true);// change to BigDecimal & avoid precision loss due to Double
    BigDecimal d = (BigDecimal) f.parse("0.9%");
```

Using DecimalFormat has the advantage that you avoid fragile String manipulations and you can even parse numbers according to your locale (DecimalSeparator, GroupingSeparator, minusSign, ...).
You could also use `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()` if you don't know the format or don't want to hardcode the it.