# Java "100%" to number

Tags: java, string-conversion

Is there a built in routine in Java that will convert a percentage to a number for example, if the string contains 100% or 100px or 100, I want a float containing 100.

Using Float.parseInt or Float.valueOf result in an exception.  I can write a routine that will parse the string and return the number, but I'm asking does this already exist?

Comment: This can be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9714333/563732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the posts and suggestions, I did try using the solution posted by eg04lt3r, however the result was translated.  In the end I wrote a simple function that does exactly what I require.  I'm sure a good regular expression would have also worked.

```
    public static double string2double(String strValue) {
        double dblValue = 0;
        if ( strValue != null ) {
            String strResult = "";
            for( int c=0; c<strValue.length(); c++ ) {
                char chr = strValue.charAt(c);

                if ( !(chr >= '0' && chr <= '9'
                   || (c == 0 && (chr == '-' || chr == '+'))
                   || (c > 0 && chr == '.')) ) {
                    break;
                }
                strResult += chr;
            }
            dblValue = Double.parseDouble(strResult);
        }
        return dblValue;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use @eg04lt3r's answer and multiply by 100? It will save you a lot of code and looks much more elegant.

Comment: Because that code only works when the value to convert ends with a % and I need a general purpose method that will work for strings that can end in either %, px or nothing at all.

Comment: You should update the question to include the details you explain here. This question currently asks to parse the string "100%". Sounds like your situation is more complex than that.

Answer (score 20):

I think you can use:

```
NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()
Number value = defaultFormat.parse("100%");
```

Comment: @brso05 That's the good point about the voting system. It also shows how many users don't care about the validity of an answer as long it looks nice.

Comment: @SPlatten use `NumberFormat defaultFormat = new DecimalFormat();` and you get what you want.

Comment: @SPlatten You could use `floatValue()` and multiply the result by 100.

Comment: @Tom, it's working  to parse percent value but it's returns factor. And it's better way, then use string buffer or pattern for this. Also if it tries to parse wrong value will throw exception which add validation for this value.

Comment: Nice solution! Using an electronic calculator, pressing "100%" and then "=" it will also display 1.

Comment: For the record, returning 1 is more mathematically correct than what OP wants because % literally means divide by a hundred. So 100%=1. Just multiply by 100 to get the actual number.

Comment: @Arc676 it doesn't matter if it is "more mathematically correct" we are here to answer the OP's question.

Comment: Is the fix for this not as simple as multiplying the answer by 100.0?

Answer (score 1):

Your comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34897218/1756430) indicates that you need to support the string ending in "%", "px", or nothing at all. If the only content of the string is the number and the unit, than you should be able to get away with:

```
float floatValue = new DecimalFormat("0.0").parse(stringInput).floatValue();
```

If your number is surrounded by other jibberish inside of the string, and you only desire the first number that occurs, than you can utilize `ParsePosition`:

```
String stringInput = "Some jibberish 100px more jibberish.";

int i = 0;
while (!Character.isDigit(stringInput.charAt(i))) i++;

float floatValue = new DecimalFormat("0.0").parse(stringInput, new ParsePosition(i)).floatValue();
```

Both of these solutions will give you the float value without requiring you to multiply the result by 100.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuffer to remove the `%` sign and then you can convert it.

```
if (percent.endsWith("%")) {
    String number = new StringBuffer(percent).deleteCharAt(percent.length() - 1);
    float f = Float.valueOf(number);
} else [Exception handling]
```

The approach above is nicer, but I figured I would fix my answer regarding the comment. You would have to make sure you are dealing with percent before removing a character.

Comment: This will definitely work, but this borders on a hack, because it assumes that there's no characters after `%`. Adding any characters after `%` would break this approach.