# Java Percentage to show decimals

Tags: java

I wrote a program today and I need to show percentage in my output but if I have an input of .05375 I need it to display as 5.375% 
I thought I could do that by using a NumberFormat but my final display is simply 5%. Is there a a way to make it show the decimals? Or how would I code around this? The program functions properly it's just that one output that needs to be formatted differently.
Below is what I have for my output for that line of code right now.

```
    System.out.println("Interest Rate:  " + percent.format(InterestRate));
```

Comment: one of the requirements for the formatting is I need to show 3 decimal places.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you format a fractional percentage with java.text.MessageFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698261/how-do-you-format-a-fractional-percentage-with-java-text-messageformat)

Comment: @Veger I didnt see that post when I searched. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that using NumberFormat in Java. Below is the sample code:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);

System.out.println("Interest Rate:  " + numberFormat.format(InterestRate));
```

A better approach is to use NumberFormat with Locale, as below:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(someLocale);
```

Comment: I had to change it to setMaximumFractionDigits(3); because of another calculation but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You still need to multiply by 100 somewhere.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Are you sure Peter? It worked for me when I coded it to get the percent instance which tells it to display a percentage (I think it's telling java to multiply by 100 there) and then I set the maximum fraction digits which allowed for my decimal point. I have run several successful tests but I'm new to this so I'm not 100% with Java.

Comment: If the interest rate is `.05375` as you state, it will print it as `0.053` with three decimal places.  If its working for you, the number must actually be `5.375`

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
System.out.printf("Interest Rate:  %.3f%%%n", 100 * InterestRate);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use the `%` format, the number is multiplied by `100` for you:

```
new DecimalFormat("%#0.000").format(rate);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `0.000` for three decimal places?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah, skimmed it:(

Comment: I took it from `I need it to display as 5.375%` but I know what you mean. ;)

Comment: the % symbol causes the value to be multipled by 100, you don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: @dube thank you. I didn't realise that. I learned something :)

Answer (score 1):

Selected answer is correct, but be sure to use

```
NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
```

which will aid nicely in dealing with the percent. None of the additional string concatenation or formatting necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `String.format();`
Refer to the docs for the format specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
double myVal = 0.05375
System.out.println("Interest Rate: " + (myVal*100) + "%" );
```

This should give you 5.375%

Is that similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: Where should the '%' come from?